# Class in not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, interface, abstract

```
public interface Selectable {
     boolean getSelected();
     void setSelected();
     Shape contains(int x, int y); 
}

public class Square extends Rectangle implements Selectable {

    int side;
    boolean selected;

    public Square(int side){
        super(side);
        this.side = side;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return " is square with side: " + side + ". It's area is: " + getArea() + "\n";
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean getSelected(){
        return selected;
    }

    public Shape contains(int x, int y){

    }
}
```

doesn't compile

```
error: Square is not abstract and does not override abstract method setSelected() in Selectable
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Emphasis on **does not override abstract method setSelected()**.

Comment: Your error appears to be that your `Square` class does not override the abstract method `setSelected()`. It's also not `abstract` which would allow it to not implement this method. Sounds like your solutions are to make it `abstract` or to implement `setSelected()`. Error message is pretty clear :)

Comment: Fix the signature of your setter in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

In your interface change

```
void setSelected();
```

to

```
void setSelected(boolean selected);
```